# Basis of finite field as vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

If we consider GF(8) as a vector space over GF(2), what are the basis for GF(8)? and How  can we define a dual space for GF(8) as a vector space?

Comment: How do you define the dual space? Normally it is just linear functions from $GF(8)$ to $GF(2)$. It sounds a little bit like you would like to identify the dual space with $GF(8)$ itself. To that end you need to give a non-degenerate bilinear form on $GF(8)$. More often than not the trace form $\langle x,y\rangle=tr(xy)$ is used for that purpose. The usual transpose is  w.r.t. the dual basis. Give us more details!

Comment: And mind you, there are several bases to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Since GF(8) is the polynomial ring over GF(2) modulo some irreducible cubic polynomial $p(x)$ over GF(2), you can just take the monomials $1$, $x$, $x^2$ for a basis. Surely, from this you can work out the dual space, by taking linear combinations of coefficients of polynomials representing elements of GF(8)?

Comment: May you give more details on constructing transpose of Frobenius map over GF(8) ? Beacuse I need dual space of GF(8) for transpose of frobenius map.